# AWS EC2 Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS: deb command-not-found

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, deb

When I tried to install mongoDb in my AWS EC2 Linux instance:Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS,

```
deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen
```

I get this following error, meaning deb command is not found.

```
$ deb Sorry, command-not-found has crashed! Please file a bug report
at: https://bugs.launchpad.net/command-not-found/+filebug Please
include the following information with the report:
 
command-not-found version: 0.2.44
```

Can someone please help me find out how to install deb in my AWS instance?

Comment: This question would be better suited for [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) or [superuser](http://superuser.com).

Comment: don't forget to run: wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Deb is not a command. You need to edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and add the following line

```
deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen
```

to the end of the file.

Then, update your system and then install MongoDB. Assuming mongodb is the package you need then run these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mongodb
```

Comment: Yes you're correct, i just found my assumption to this error is wrong. i fixed it just now. Thanks for your answer :). will mark yours as an answer in 8 mins.